# I cannot navigate between screens in a released apk

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, react-navigation

i am new to react native and it would be great if someone can help me with my problem.
I am creating an app using expo in which i have created a stack navigation. It works fine when i run it on the expo-go app but when i build an apk for my app, the buttons which are supposed to navigate between screens stops working. When i click those buttons, they don't do anything.
I am also using `react-native-maps` and `google maps api` for displaying a map and markers on it.

Firstly, i am unable to identify whether stack navigation is causing this or `react-native-maps`.
Secondly, please tell how to solve this.

**STACK NAVIGATION FILE:-**

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Ambulance from "../screens/Ambulance";
import Hospitals from "../screens/Hospitals";
import Pharmacy from "../screens/Pharmacy";
import ChatBot from "../screens/ChatBot";


const { Navigator, Screen } = createStackNavigator()


const StackNav = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Navigator headerMode='none'>
                <Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
                <Screen name='Ambulance' component={Ambulance} />
                <Screen name='Hospitals' component={Hospitals} />
                <Screen name='Pharmacy' component={Pharmacy} />
                <Screen name='Chatbot' component={ChatBot} />
            </Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}



export default StackNav
```

**App.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

import StackNav from './routes/StackNav';


const getfonts = () =>
    Font.loadAsync({
        'montserrat': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf'),
        'geometos': require('./assets/fonts/Geometos.ttf'),
    })


export default function App() {
  const [font, setFont] = useState(false)

    if (font){
        return (
            <StackNav />
        );
    } 

    else{
        return (
            <AppLoading 
                startAsync={getfonts}
                onFinish={() => setFont(true)}
                onError={console.warn}
            />
        )
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

check installation of

```js
expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

or try to uninstall react navigation then reinstall it.

```js
//uninstall
yarn remove @react-navigation/native
yarn remove @react-navigation/native-stack
```

```js
//install again
yarn add @react-navigation/native
expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
yarn add @react-navigation/native-stack
```